# Make remove directory from every path in array

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So far, I have been compiling my c and c++ (and a little glsl) project with a shell script that recompiles the whole thing even when I wanted to make a small, simple change. It started taking almost 5 seconds. I couldn't stand for that, so I turned to Makefiles. I think my Makefile is good so far except for one problem: When I convert my `CSOURCES` to `COBJECTS`, I don't remove the directory that the source file is in, so I get these errors:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'lib/key_store.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'lib/logger.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'lib/myglutils.o'
```

Here's the makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CPPC=g++
CCFLAGS=-std=c11 -Wall -pedantic
CPPFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic
INC=-Iinclude/
LDFLAGS=lib/libGLEW.a lib/libglfw3.a -framework OpenGL -framework CoreVideo -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit
CSOURCES=$(wildcard lib/*.c)
COBJECTS=$(CSOURCES:.c=.o)
CPPSOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
CPPOBJECTS=$(CPPSOURCES:.cpp=.o)
TARGET=Ultra-Fighters

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(COBJECTS) $(CPPOBJECTS)
    $(CPPC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp %.hpp
    $(CPPC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INC) -c $<

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CPPC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INC) -c $<

%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c $<

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

My question is: How do I remove the directory part of the path from `CSOURCES` when I assign to `COBJECTS`?

Comment: Neither the linked duplicate nor `vpath` are direct answers here. Though `vpath` is quite possibly a good answer in other ways. The correct answer here would likely be the `$(notdir)` function.

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried that, but I think I used it wrong, how would I use it in this line: `COBJECTS=$(CSOURCES:.c=.o)`?

Comment: @EtanReisner May be I was judging too quickly. Reopening to give you room for an answer or marking a better duplicate.

Comment: Do you want the object files created from `.c` files under `lib` to be created under `lib/` or do you want them created in the current directory as they are now?

Comment: @EtanReisner current directory

Comment: That'll collide if you ever have a `.cpp` and `.c` file with the same name but ok.

Comment: @EtanReisner They won't have the same names

Comment: And that's a find assertion until it happens for some reason but it doesn't matter. It would just have changed the possible valid answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly hacky, direct solution to your problem is [`notdir`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html).

Comment: Not a hack if that's the goal. That's what the function is there for. That's why I said that in my original comment. Whether that's the right solution here is a different question.

Comment: I know that that's the command to use, but I dont know how to use it in this context: `COBJECTS=$(CSOURCES:.c=.o)`